# Python: How to input numbers in list between two numbers based on user input?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input

```
start = int(input("Enter starting number: "))
stop = int(input("Enter number to stop viewing at: "))
numbers = [start:stop]
```

This gives me a syntax error. I can't even use `numbers.append[start:stop]`
Any way I can use something *like* list slicing to *input* numbers into a list?

Comment: so, if a start=1 and stop=5, numbers=[1,2,3,4,5] ???

Comment: The first syntax error is probably from  this line: `stop = int(input(Enter number to stop viewing at: "))` You're missing a quotation.

Comment: @glls yes, also if i could put in floats (at a rounded of 2 digits), that's be great

Comment: @Farhan.K oh sorry, I forgot that in the question, it's written correctly in the actual code.

Comment: you can, view the below info, it is pretty straightforward on pythons documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct way to generate a list. If you want a list of numbers based on input you can use this:

```
start = int(input("Enter starting number: "))
stop = int(input("Enter number to stop viewing at: "))
numbers = [i for i in range(start,stop+1)]
```

You might want to read up on [`lists`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: `[i for i in range(start,stop+1)]` is a complicated way to write `list(range(start, stop + 1))`.

Comment: @Matthias I wouldn't say it's complicated. It's basic list comprehension.

Comment: You're right, a list comprehension isn't exactly rocket science, but nevertheless it's more complicated than just using a call to `list`.

Answer (score 0):

if my comment is the case, you can append items in your list, based on range as follows:

```
start = int(input("Enter starting number: "))
stop = int(input("Enter number to stop viewing at: "))
numbers=[]
for i in range(start, stop+1):
    numbers.append(i)

print list
```

for [rounding digits](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html):

> round(number[, ndigits])
>
> Return the floating point value number
>   rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. If ndigits is
>   omitted, it defaults to zero. The result is a floating point number.
>   Values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus
>   ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away
>   from 0 (so, for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0).

from python orgs documentation.

Comment: or just, `numbers = range(start, stop+1)`. Its better not to change the definition of `list` which is a keyword. I didnt notice that this is 3.x. Here, `numbers = list(range(start, stop+1))` may be useful ...